# Is there a way to wrap this JS call neatly?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

Let's say I have:

```
var details = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/',
        async: true,
        params: {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'},
        headers: {'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'},
        contentType: 'text'
};

kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 200 && data.response != null) {
                var text = data.response;
                kango.console.log(text);
        }
        else { // something went wrong
                kango.console.log('something went wrong');
        }
});
```

Is there a way to wrap it more neatly somehow  - like the only variables I really change is GET / POST, so I'm thinking something like:

`call('POST', function(data) {});`

Is this possible?

I'm not familiar enough with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the logic in another function like this:

```
function getData(method) {
var details = {
        method: method,
        url: 'http://example.com/',
        async: true,
        params: {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'},
        headers: {'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'},
        contentType: 'text'
};

kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 200 && data.response != null) {
                var text = data.response;
                kango.console.log(text);
        }
        else { // something went wrong
                kango.console.log('something went wrong');
        }
});
}
```

and call it with `getData('POST')` or `getData('GET')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Call(method,callback){
    var details = {
            method: method,
            url: 'http://example.com/',
            async: true,
            params: {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'},
            headers: {'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'},
            contentType: 'text'
    };

    kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) {
            if (data.status == 200 && data.response != null) {
                  if (typeof callback === "function") {
                    callback.call(kango,data);
                  }
            }
            else { // something went wrong
                    kango.console.log('something went wrong');
            }
    });
}
```

To improve code quality, you should:

- Do a check `typeof callback === "function"` to ensure that the parameter passed in is a function.
- `callback.call(kango,data);` to pass the `kango` as the context. Inside the callback function you can use `this` to access. This would create a more loosely coupled code.